# iPhone won't pass web app requested data after installing .mobileconfig file

Tags: php, ios, iphone, udid

I'm writing a web app which requests use of the users UDID with a .mobileconfig file which is formatted like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>PayloadContent</key>
        <dict>
            <key>URL</key>
            <string>https://example.com/profile/enroll</string>
            <key>DeviceAttributes</key>
            <array>
                <string>UDID</string>
                <string>IMEI</string>
                <string>ICCID</string>
                <string>VERSION</string>
                <string>PRODUCT</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
        <string>www.example.com</string>
        <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
        <string>Profile Service</string>
        <key>PayloadVersion</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>PayloadUUID</key>
        <string>3956C530-18F0-4B3D-B4C5-XXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
        <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.example.profile-service</string>
        <key>PayloadDescription</key>
        <string>This temporary profile will be used to find and display your current device's UDID.</string>
        <key>PayloadType</key>
        <string>Profile Service</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I have signed this profile with the same certificate I am using for SSL, and it shows up as verified when the user clicks on the profile. However, after choosing to install the profile, no data is passed back to my server. I've tried using `'php://input'` and `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` but both are empty when the page loads. I have determined that the page is actually loading, because I can `echo` things in the PHP file and they show up. Is there something that I am obviously doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you're wanting pipe the app itself (or something) to the output buffer. For that, you'll want [php://output](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

You can do a one-liner pretty quick with that one using [stream_copy_to_stream](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php):
stream_copy_to_stream(file://..., php://output);

If that's not the case, please let me know what I'm missing from your description.

Comment: The basic process is the above file gets signed and placed on the server. Then, when an iDevice loads that file, it will open the profile in the settings app. When the user installs it, the device *should* then load the page listed in under the 'URL' key, with the requested info as the POST data. However, my site is not receiving any data despite the fact that the device does load the page.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm afraid in that instance I'm of little to no help beyond the really obvious stuff, like ensuring its a POST and not  GET where you can see they're hitting the page, and doing a var_dump($_POST) or something of the like to make sure its not getting stuck away somewhere. Thanks for explaining though, I'll leave this here in case someone else comes along..

Answer (score 0):

The data is sent with POST.

`print_r($_POST);`

and you should see what is being sent